# Would like to add some custom ajax & javascript to activeadmin based application

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activeadmin

Hi guys I'm working on this application using activeadmin. I've come to a point where I would like to add in some ajax based functions. I have the basic form set up using teh activeadmin resource and it generates a very pretty form.

I would like to while the user is entering the details on the form - run a ajax call which would retrieve some html based on the values being entered and populate it on the page.

More likely I would like a way to add custom javascript to the page. Whats the best way to do this - I'm facing issues with returning html without the entire activeadmin layout coming with it.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `/config/initializers/active_admin.rb`

You can add javascript resources like this:

```
config.register_javascript 'my_functions.js'
```

Comment: Thanks, was having trouble how to figure out how to do this for ChartKick, was about to write a bunch of custom code, when I stumbled on this answer that turned it into just two lines:
`config.register_javascript "//www.google.com/jsapi"`
`config.register_javascript "chartkick"`

Answer (score 2):

I use to put code directly to /app/assets/javascripts/active_admin.js

You can also include script in /config/initializers/active_admin.rb